# The animation for my programatically created button acts weird in my application

Tags: java, android, firebase, animation

So I am facing a weird bug I cannot explain - I cannot even reproduce it sometimes.

Basic context:

- I have an application, which lists objects. Every object has a name and a point value. For every object, the addCustomSpinner function creates a "ticket" (a custom view, kind-of-spinner) and shows them in a scrollview so the user can select the one needed. There are four different 'containers' for four different kind of objects - so the layout can be populated with four kind of "ticket" package.
- The data for the objects are collected from a database. The addCustomSpinner is called with a for cycle for every object in the database, and - Important - before the for method, the Layout it populates with the tickets is cleared (removeAllViews).
- Inside addCustomSpinner, everything is created as "new" - like the button in question.
- addCustomSpinner creates this button and adds a new onClickListener. Inside onClickListener, a new boolean is created - this is used to show a different animation when the button is clicked again. On first click (boolean = true), the arrow turns 180 degrees and faces upwards, on second click (boolean = false) the arrow turns 180 degrees and faces downwards. Works like a charm, until...

The bug I am facing:

- Sometimes - as I already mentioned, not every time - if I click the button for one "ticket", then leave it 'opened' and click on an another one, and leave it 'opened' also, THEN I choose to populate the layout with a different kind of "ticket" package - The arrow faces upwards by default on every ticket in every package! Sometimes - again, just sometimes - with the same pattern I can turn it back, but it happens just "by accident".

I don't understand how the animation and state of the buttons can be connected, if every created ticket is new, every button is new, every onClickListener is new, and every boolean inside onClickListener is new. And if these are connected somehow, then why can that be that every behavior is "unique" for the buttons, nothing else shows any connection - even this is just a "sometimes" bug, a pretty rare one.

Can anybody help me why this happens?

What I tried:
Well, tried to trace the issue - but since it happens just by accident, I have no clue, I just searched if I can do anything else than the boolean to add different animation for the clicks. Sadly using ObjectAnimator is not a good solution for me - not the same result at least, since my animated arrow not only rotates, but it also changes its color. Shapeshifter seemed like a good idea to create animations easily, but now as I see it, maybe a simple rotation will be my ultimate solution.

Here's the code for the button:

```
customButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        boolean isCustomButtonClicked = true;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isCustomButtonClicked) {
                customButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.avd_anim_arrow_blue_back);
                Drawable d = customButton.getDrawable();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    if (d instanceof AnimatedVectorDrawable) {
                        animArrowAnim = (AnimatedVectorDrawable) d;
                        animArrowAnim.start();
                    }
                }
                routeWhoClimbed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                isCustomButtonClicked = false;
            } else if (!isCustomButtonClicked) {
                customButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.avd_anim_arrow_blue);
                Drawable d = customButton.getDrawable();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    if (d instanceof AnimatedVectorDrawable) {
                        animArrowAnim = (AnimatedVectorDrawable) d;
                        animArrowAnim.start();
                    }
                }
                routeWhoClimbed.setVisibility(GONE);
                isCustomButtonClicked = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

EDIT:
The full addCustomSpinner():

private void addCustomSpinner(Routes mRouteItemToAdd, String placeName) {

//creating a new View for my custom layout created in xml

```
    View customRoutesView = new View(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams customViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    customRoutesView.setLayoutParams(customViewParams);

    customRoutesView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
            R.layout.custom_view_layout, routeLayout, false
    );
```

//Setting up the views inside the custom view

```
    ImageView imageViewDiffImage = customRoutesView.findViewById(R.id.routeDiffImageView);
    TextView textViewRouteName = customRoutesView.findViewById(R.id.routeNameTextView);
    TextView textViewRouteDiff = customRoutesView.findViewById(R.id.routeDiffTextView);
    ImageButton customButton = customRoutesView.findViewById(R.id.customButton);
    RadioButton climberNameOne = customRoutesView.findViewById(R.id.climberNameOne);
    RadioButton climberNameTwo = customRoutesView.findViewById(R.id.climberNameTwo);
    Button climbedItButton = customRoutesView.findViewById(R.id.climbed_it_button);
    RadioGroup climberNameRadioGroup = customRoutesView.findViewById(R.id.climberNameRadioGroup);
    RadioGroup climbingStyleRadioGroup = customRoutesView.findViewById(R.id.styleNameRadioGroup);
    RelativeLayout routeWhoClimbed = customRoutesView.findViewById(R.id.routeWhoClimbedRelativeLayout);

    imageViewDiffImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.muscle);
    textViewRouteName.setText(mRouteItemToAdd.name);
    textViewRouteDiff.setText("Difficulty: " + (int) mRouteItemToAdd.difficulty);

    climberNameOne.setText(climberName1);
    climberNameTwo.setText(climberName2);

    routeWhoClimbed.setVisibility(GONE);
```

//Here comes the button with the animated image

```
    customButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        boolean isCustomButtonClicked = true;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isCustomButtonClicked) {
                customButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.avd_anim_arrow_blue_back);
                Drawable d = customButton.getDrawable();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    if (d instanceof AnimatedVectorDrawable) {
                        animArrowAnim = (AnimatedVectorDrawable) d;
                        animArrowAnim.start();
                    }
                }
                routeWhoClimbed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                isCustomButtonClicked = false;
            } else if (!isCustomButtonClicked) {
                customButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.avd_anim_arrow_blue);
                Drawable d = customButton.getDrawable();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    if (d instanceof AnimatedVectorDrawable) {
                        animArrowAnim = (AnimatedVectorDrawable) d;
                        animArrowAnim.start();
                    }
                }
                routeWhoClimbed.setVisibility(GONE);
                isCustomButtonClicked = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

//Button, works like an 'OK' or something, and I have no
//problem with this

```
    climbedItButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int checkedNameButton = climberNameRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            int checkedStyleButton = climbingStyleRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            RadioButton checkedNameRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedNameButton);
            RadioButton checkedStyleRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedStyleButton);
            String checkedName = (String) checkedNameRadioButton.getText();
            String checkedStyle = (String) checkedStyleRadioButton.getText();

            addClimbToDatabase(user.getUid(), checkedName, mRouteItemToAdd, placeName, checkedStyle);
        }
    });
```

//And finally, I add this new "ticket" with the custom view to the layout i want to show it. Again, this also works like a charm, no problem here.

```
    routeLayout.addView(customRoutesView);
}
```

Comment: You may need to post more code,`addCustomSpinner` function with the whole view generation, im assuming this is done in a `Adapter`?

Comment: Hi, okay, I will. About the addCustomSpinner - it creates a new view, inflates it with a custom xml, initializes all the view items in the custom xml as new (just like this button), then adds this onclicklistener for the new button. Finally, it adds the new view to the root layout where i want to show the "tickets".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I did not manage to understand the problem throughly, but I was able to eliminate it.

So during my fixing tries I narrowed down the problem to the animated drawable state - credit to @avalerio for his pro tip, but the answer wasn't addig an id to the button. I think somehow and sometime, the state of the first animation (turning the arrow 180 degrees) stuck in the end position - causing the other views using this animatedDrawable showing it in end position on start.

.reset() did not help, since it resets the animatedVectorDrawable object, not the animation xml drawable state. My solution is a kind of workaround, but it is working: when the custom-view 'ticket' is created with the animated-drawable-imagebutton, I set the imageResource of the button to a not-animated xml drawable - this drawable is basically the start position of my animated-drawable. This way, when the 'tickets' are generated, the imagebutton is 'hardcoded' in the start position.

Not elegant, but works. BUT(!) I would really appreciate if someone could explain to me how this weird behavior is possible - just sometimes, randomly, with no pattern I can reproduce intentionally.